# How to stop Heap Analytics grouping assets into "OTHER" Category

Tags: analytics, heap-analytics

I think this might be very simple.

I wrote a query in heap to tell me which users were part of an event and how many times they engaged in it during the year.
The result is a simple table with username and number of occurrences.

It worked. However, Heap has this weird behavior of choosing multiple results (maybe at random?) and throwing them into a single "Other (X other results)" category. Where x is a number of others.
So i end up with a table of 20 maybe 30 users and occurences, and one row of "Other (X other results)".

I shrunk the query to see results from a smaller subset of dates and the "Other" category disappeared.

I really need to see every individual row in my query results! Even if it's paginated.
Help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can export the result as a CSV. The downloaded file will contain all the results (all single entries without the grouped OTHER).

Inte the current UI, you can find **Export to CSV** at the top of the report view.

[image]